# xlsx database ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist, xlsx

I'm writing an iphone application that pulls xlsx file from the server, manipulates with it (reading and writing to it) and upload it to the server. So I need to convert it to plist format, do some operations with plist and convert plist back to xlsx and upload it to server.
How the convertion xlsx->plist and plist->xlsx could be done on ios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you will need to achieve your task:

*Note: You must do the heavy lifting*

To parse an *xlsx*, you will need to understand the Open XML file formats:  [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx)

To parse a *plist*, you will need to understand the Property List file format: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html)

To parse, I recommend using the NSXMLParser: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)