# How to convert a binary xlsx file into NSString?

Tags: ios, swift, binary, nsstring, inputstream

I have a xlsx-file which I try to convert to a NSString.
Since I´m not a professional, I´m dependent on what I find in in different posts.

What I found is this:

```
if let stream:InputStream = InputStream(fileAtPath: path) {

     var buf:[UInt8] = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 16)

     stream.open()

     while true {

          let len = stream.read(&buf, maxLength: buf.count)
          print("len \(len)")
          for i in 0..<len {
               print(String(format:"%02x ", buf[i]), terminator: "")
          }
          if len < buf.count {
               break
          }
     }
     stream.close()
}
```

This gives me the following output:

```
len 16
50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 52 46 91 4b 00 00 len 16
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 64 6f len 16
63 50 72 6f 70 73 2f 63 6f 72 65 2e 78 6d 6c ad len 16
91 5d 4b c3 30 14 86 ef fb 2b 42 ee db 24 2d 6e len 16
23 b4 1d a2 0c 04 c5 81 93 89 77 21 3d b6 c5 e6 len 16
83 24 da f9 ef cd ba 59 51 bc f4 f2 e4 7d de 87 len 16
```

If anyone could give me advice how I could convert this into a NSString?

Comment: Are you aware that XLSX files are Microsoft Excel documents (and ZIP compressed)?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I know it is a Excel document. But ZIP compressed? How is that? I can open it with Excel without unpacking.

Comment: Sure, Excel just uses the ZIP format as a container for the various data. There is no "simple" conversion to a string. But the file format is (as far as I know) fully documented, and there are probably 3rd party libraries.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746662/xlsx-database-ios for a link to the specification.

Comment: @MartinR I see. Seems to be an advanced challenge. Thanks.